# How to multiply one floating point number by a decimal and get a floating point number

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, multiplication

I'm trying to do some math in python.  Here's my code:

```
if(height.is_integer()):
    height = int(height)
meters = height * .3048
in_m = "%d meters" % meters
print "You are also also %s tall (let's hope it doesn't round)." % (in_m)
```

As you can see I'm trying to make height any user-defined amount and then multiply that by a decimal to get a floating point number defined as meters.  The problem is that when I input a number like 6 for height or 5.25 it just rounds down to one meter.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `in_m = "%d meters" % meters`
>
> it just rounds down to one meter.

Your conversion using `%d`, applied to any numeric value, prints only its integer part. To print a value as floating one, you should use `%f`, `%e` or `%g`; for your need, `%g` seems to be the best default.

Comment: Thanks this really helped @Netch .  I was so confused.  I do have one more question.  How come it doesn't matter in some cases whether I use it like  `lbs = raw_input()
lbs = float(lbs)
if (lbs.is_integer()):
 height = int(height)
your_weight = "heavy"
your_pounds = "%d pounds %s" % (lbs, your_weight)
kg = lbs * .453592   print "In the metric system that would be %s" % (in_kg)` which gets me a nice floating point number?

Comment: @Jacusaurus your code is full of mixing variable names and unknown methods, as `is_integer`. Please make it at least not raising an exception. Also, updated code should be added to the question (better not replacing initial one), because formatting in comments is too spartan.